# scp ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.109 port 22: No route to host lost connection

Tags: networking, ip, scp, networkmanager

I use `SCP` command on Debian Linux to transfer a file to my colleague via LAN. But I encounter the problem:

```
$ scp filename.file username@10.0.0.109:/tmp
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.109 port 22: No route to host
lost connection
```

But when I use the same command to transfer the file to a WAN machine, it works well. And when I use `ping` to `ping` WAN website, it works well, but when I ping a LAN ip address, it does not work.

```
$ ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Routing table:

```
$ ip route 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 proto static
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.108 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.108
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000
```

arp -an

```
root@debian:# arp  -an
? (10.0.0.1) at c4:04:15:17:bd:66 [ether] on wlan0
```

iptables -L

```
root@debian:# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I can explore the Internet via Firefox. It just can't connect the LAN machie.

And my ip address is static ip in my company's LAN.

The port 22 is open, and there seems nothing wrong with iptables and SSH works well too.

How can I fix it?

Comment: So you are saying, from that same machine where you are trying to do `scp`, you can do `ssh username@10.0.0.109` & it works?

Comment: There is a difference between LAN and WAN, if your colleague host is "behind" a routeur, there are step to be done (namely forwarding port) before you can access hosts. You will be using his WAN IP of course. Can you give more details about network topology ?

Comment: Hi, I have update the problem in detail.

Comment: `$ssh jeff@10.0.0.109`  `ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.109 port 22: No route to host` I mean, if I scp and ssh a mahine that out of the LAN where my machine in, it works well.

Comment: Try to ping your colleague's machine from yours, and viceversa. Post the results.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this problem. I disbled eth0 and `SCP` can transfer file to my colleague via LAN.

Answer (score 1):

What I need to disable `eth0`, after that, it works fine!